# SUM and CASE Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, temp-tables

So, I have a report that is created based on a join of 5 tables. With the join of the tables, I perform some calculations, group by (roll up) and some other stuff:

| Supervisor / Salesperson | Dept | Cases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ***Supervisor 1*** | ***Dept 1*** | ***7*** |
| Salesperson 1 |  | 5 |
| Salesperson 2 |  | 2 |
| ***Supervisor 2*** | ***Dept 2*** | ***9*** |
| Salesperson 3 |  | 5 |
| Salesperson 4 |  | 3 |
| Salesperson 5 |  | 2 |
| Salesperson 6 |  | 1 |

The cases column is calculated based on a SUM(table1.column1/table1.column2)

What I need to do is to check if the cases number is greater than or equals to 3 and flag it, so ideal final result would be (instead of yes and no, could also return 1 and 0):

| Supervisor / Salesperson | Dept | Cases | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***Supervisor 1*** | ***Dept 1*** | ***7*** | Yes |
| Salesperson 1 |  | 5 | Yes |
| Salesperson 2 |  | 2 | No |
| ***Supervisor 2*** | ***Dept 2*** | ***9*** | Yes |
| Salesperson 3 |  | 5 | Yes |
| Salesperson 4 |  | 3 | Yes |
| Salesperson 5 |  | 2 | No |
| Salesperson 6 |  | 1 | No |

I'm stuck on how to do that, someone can give me any idea? Is there a way to do that without creating a temp table?
My SQL flavor is Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column after the `case` column that checks if result, thus:

Using [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html):

```
SUM(table1.column1/table1.column2) as case
,iff(case >= 3, 'Yes', 'No') as Flag
```

```
select 
    supervisor, 
    dept,
    SUM(column1/column2) as "Case",
    iff("Case" >= 3, 'Yes', 'No') as flag
from values
    (30,3, 'a', 'c'),
    (10,2, 'b', 'b'),
    (8,4, 'a', 'b')
    as t(column1, column2, supervisor, dept )
group by rollup (1,2);
```

gives:

| SUPERVISOR | DEPT | Case | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | c | 10 | Yes |
| b | b | 5 | Yes |
| a | b | 2 | No |
| a | null | 12 | Yes |
| b | null | 5 | Yes |
| null | null | 17 | Yes |

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I'm getting an error that aggregate functions can't be nested :(

Comment: so that notes, you are running this in a bigger picture. Thus something will need to become a sub-select so the context/scope of the aggregate/window functions is more explicit for the SQL compiler.